# Algorithm to encode Huffman tree

Tags: algorithm, matlab, huffman-code

I have a program which encodes sequence, i.e. creates codewords using Huffman method.

I need to encode the tree itself, where node=0, leaf=1. It should be something like a binary heap i guess, where first element (0) says that it has 2 children, next two elements (ex., 00) also have two children each, next four (10 00) - have one leaf and 3 non-leaf children and so on

I have a result for given sequence, but i have no idea how to get it.

```
function [  ] = encodeTwoPassHuff(  )
global CODE
global codeTree
codeTree=[];
clc;

inputStr='IF_WE_CANNOT_DO_AS_WE_WOULD_WE_SHOULD_DO_AS_WE_CAN';
a=unique(inputStr);
N=size(inputStr,2);
Nx = zeros(1, size(a, 2));
for i = 1:size(a,2)
     for j = 1:N        
        if (a(i) == inputStr(j))
             Nx(i) = Nx(i)+1;
        end
     end
end
for i = 1 : size(a, 2)
    prob(i) = Nx(i) / N;
end


CODE = cell( length(prob), 1 );


p=prob;
s = cell( length(p), 1 );
for i = 1:length(p)
    s{i} = i;   
end

while size(s, 1) > 2
    [p,i] = sort(p, 'ascend');
    p(2) = p(1) + p(2);
    p(1) = [];
    s = s(i);           
    s{2} = {s{1},s{2}}; 
    s(1) = [];          
end


CODE = makecode(s, []);    


fprintf('00010000010100110111101101111\n'); % encoded tree (true)
fprintf('%d', codeTree); % my result
fprintf('\n');

for i = 1:length(CODE)
    len(i) = length(CODE{i});
end

% print
disp('symbol | probabil | len | codeword');
for i=1:length(prob)
        fprintf('%5s\t %.4f\t %3d\t %s\n', a(i), prob(i), len(i), num2str(CODE{i}));
end

end 


function [CODE]=makecode(ss, codeword)
global CODE
global codeTree

if isa(ss,'cell')   % node
    codeTree = [codeTree 0];
    makecode( ss{1}, [codeword 1] );
    makecode( ss{2}, [codeword 0] );

else                % leaf
    CODE{ss} = char('0' + codeword);
    codeTree = [codeTree 1];
end
end
```

`

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a Huffman tree.

Comment: @beaker , oh well, maybe you can improve it somehow? I thought it's okay as far as it gives the same average codeword length as proven Huffman code.

Comment: I don't see how you can make that claim when not only can you not generate the tree, but your code does not work. You haven't even sufficiently described what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you just encode the lengths of the code words for each symbol.  For example, if you build your tree and you get

```
A -> 10
B -> 0
C -> 111
D -> 110
```

The you just write out the lengths array like [2,1,3,3]

Of course, there are lots of trees that produce the same code lengths, but it doesn't matter which one you use, since they are all equally efficient.

The sender and receiver do have to use the *same* tree, though, so after writing out the lengths, the sender builds a new tree from the lengths in exactly the same way that the receiver will, e.g.,

```
A -> 00
B -> 1
C -> 010
D -> 011
```

As long as the sender and receiver build the same tree, everything works fine, and you have avoided transmitting all the redundant information that would distinguish one equivalent tree from another.

Comment: That's reasonable, i see, still I want do encode the tree the way i described